# RNN unrolling length

Tags: time-series, rnn

I am trying to build a RNN that can take time series as input for example from various sensors.
While building the RNN there are a couple of initial lengths that must be defined.
The size of the cell and the length of how much you will unroll the RNN.

From what i understand, cell size is arbitrary and can be modified independent of how the inputs are shaped. But how much you will unroll the RNN depends on your input length.

If i have a time series of 1 hour consisting of 1000 values, should i choose to unroll the RNN 1000 times, or is it too much?
My goal is to classify the whole time series, and ideally i want all 1000 time steps to be taken into account for this classification.